# The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Hola formatee el Windows para 64 bits  a la hora de ejecutar el pgAmin 4 me sale ese error.
Espero que me puedan ayudar a solucionarlo

Error:

> pgAdmin Runtime Environment
> -------------------------------------------------------- Python Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe" Runtime
> Config File:
> "C:\Users\Duster\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json" pgAdmin
> Config File: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py"
> Webapp Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin
> 4\web\pgAdmin4.py" pgAdmin Command: "C:\Program
> Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe -s C:\Program
> Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py" Environment:
>
> - ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
> - APPDATA: C:\Users\Duster\AppData\Roaming
> - CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \.\pipe\crashpad_4860_YOLTTCBOTIVCNFTV
> - CHROME_RESTART: NW.js|¡Vaya! Se ha producido un fallo en NW.js. ¿Quieres reiniciar el navegador ahora?|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
> - CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
> - CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
> - CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
> - COMPUTERNAME: DUSTER-PC
> - ComSpec: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
> - FP_NO_HOST_CHECK: NO
> - HOMEDRIVE: C:
> - HOMEPATH: \Users\Duster
> - LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\Duster\AppData\Local
> - LOGONSERVER: \DUSTER-PC
> - NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 2
> - OS: Windows_NT
> - Path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows
>   Live
> - PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
> - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: bf0f0bf7-a0b2-44d3-906f-1b56cc803359
> - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 62609
> - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
> - PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
> - PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
> - PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 6
> - PROCESSOR_REVISION: 2a07
> - ProgramData: C:\ProgramData
> - ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
> - ProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)
> - ProgramW6432: C:\Program Files
> - PSModulePath: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
> - PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
> - SESSIONNAME: Console
> - SystemDrive: C:
> - SystemRoot: C:\Windows
> - TEMP: C:\Users\Duster\AppData\Local\Temp
> - TMP: C:\Users\Duster\AppData\Local\Temp
> - USERDOMAIN: Duster-PC
> - USERNAME: Duster
> - USERPROFILE: C:\Users\Duster
> - windir: C:\Windows
> - windows_tracing_flags: 3
> - windows_tracing_logfile: C:\BVTBin\Tests\installpackage\csilogfile.log
>
> ---
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
> Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 16, in 
> from cheroot.wsgi import Server as CherootServer   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin
> 4\python\lib\site-packages\cheroot\wsgi.py", line 36, in 
> from . import server   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin
> 4\python\lib\site-packages\cheroot\server.py", line 70, in 
> import email.utils   File "", line 259, in load_module   File "email\utils.py", line 29, in    File
> "", line 259, in load_module   File "socket.py",
> line 49, in  ImportError: DLL load failed while importing
> _socket: El par�metro no es correcto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]